# assembly - simple code error - accessing array element

Tags: assembly

I'm having trouble with this simple assembly code. There is an array called vet as an input for the assembly code.

```
xor ecx, exc
xor eax, eax
add eax, vet[ecx*0]
cmp EAX, 0xE2
je err
nerr : mov error, 0
jmp end
err : mov error, 1
end : mov error, 0
```

Basically I'm trying to verify if the first element of an array is 226, then error will contain 1, else 0.

The array contains bytes. I can't find where's the error (can't compile), so that's why the code might seem confused (too much redundance).

Is there a problem with accessing to the array? I've done multiple tries and it seems like it's not the correct way but I think it should be.

Comment: You need not to compile, You need to assemble and link, what is the errormessage of these steps? Also, if working with arrays, try to use esi and edi for such and similar operations. Those registers exist mainly for array operations.

Answer (score 0):

`add eax, vet[ecx*0]` is not valid. The part in `[]` is the offset, and is of the form `pointer[offset+index*size_of_elements]`. In your case, the offset is omitted, `ecx` is the index, which is fine, but the size of the elements is 0, which is absurd (and not valid). If your array contains bytes, the instruction should be `add eax, vet[ecx*1]`. In your case, you will access the first element by setting `ecx` to 0, like you already did.

Also, if you want to load the value into `eax`, you can just do `mov eax, vet[ecx*1]`, instead of zeroing and adding. You can also put the `vet[ecx*1]` directly in a comparison instruction.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `exc` is obviously a typo. And `*0` does not exist in a memory operand, and is silly anyway (don't use that register then?). Now the real stuff

```
je err
nerr : mov error, 0
jmp end
err : mov error, 1
end : mov error, 0
```

Follow the paths.

Path 1, fall-through. Put 0 in `error`, jump to `end`, put 0 in `error` again. Ok, that's a bit odd, but loading the some thing twice isn't really a problem.

Path 2, branch to `err`. What goes in `error`? First 1, but then 0, *not good*.

This can be fixed really easily, just remove the second `mov error, 0`.

---

But there is more. We can use `setcc`. Also that business at the start is overly verbose. How about (not tested)

```
cmp byte ptr [vet], 226
sete al
movzx eax, al
mov dword ptr [error], eax
```